# AngularJS (Angular 1) no funciona en producción

Tags: angularjs, servidor, gulp

Tengo una aplicación con angularjs, trabajo con la versión 1.4.2, versión de node 4.2.6, en Ubuntu 16.04, uso gulp para la automatización de tareas, lo que sucede es que al correr la aplicación en desarrollo todo funciona, y me muestra en el navegador, pero en producción no sirve nada; hago uso de `gulp` para generar el `dist` que se sube al servidor, al dar los comandos gulp-opt plantillla y gulp opt-build lo que hace es optimizar el código, y crear la  carpeta dist que contiene el index optmizado, las carpetas img, css y js con todos los templates minimizados y optimizados,todo esto para que sea mas liviano, al dar gulp produccion arranca el servidor de producción, lo que hace es cargar esa carpeta dist y correrlo por otro puerto que yo determino en el gulpfile.js, pero el proyecto   me sale en blanco, y en el inspector de elementos un error que dice:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>
> Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template:
>   app/encabezado/encabezado.html

Con cada uno de los templates, no me encuentra los templates en producción.

**¿Por qué pasa esto?.**

Ya corregí los errores de sintáxis que muestra en consola, revise las etiquetas que todas cerraran en los html, pero sigue saliendo el error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, deberías agregar mas información sobre el error, por lo menos que versión de angular estás usando, pero en principio creo que estás usando 2/4, con lo cual, te preguntaría si configuraste el <base href="/"> en el index.html, y si tu .htaccess también maneja los rewrite. Saludos!

Comment: Gracias por responder, en realidad es angular js, es con el que estaba mas familiarizado, tengo el <base href="/"> en el index agregado.  no tengo ningún archivo .htacces.

Comment: Tu problema es por las rutas que tienes configuradas, pero es muy difícil encontrar la solución sin tus archivos o versión exacta de angular. Intenta leer esto: https://angular.io/guide/deployment, ahí te dice como configurar el href y el htaccess. Saludos

Comment: editado espero haberme explicado mejor

Comment: En el servidor tenés una carpeta app? porque de otra manera, esta ruta "app/encabezado/encabezado.html", está mal. Saludos

Comment: Edité de nuevo, esa es mi estructura de carpetas, el dist es lo que se sube al server, en el js, hay un archivo llamado app.min.js, y allí se hace uso de templatecache para inyectar los templates.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61377/discussion-between-kn-and-bastianburst).

Comment: La solucion es simple, en el app.modules o donde hagas referencia a estos, debes agregar el modulo templates, de esta forma te cargarán los archivos en producción.